Understanding proof of existence of Schreier transversals
I'm trying to understand the proof in the image attached. I'm fine with everything in the first paragraph of the proof. But I don't get why the stuff in the last sentence holds. Why is H freely generated by these loops and where does the set come from? It refers to J but I don't see how that's been defined yet (since the first part of the theorem is proving it exists).


Please do not rely on pictures of text

I see only four lines you yourself wrote, And none of it provides context.

Your question is answered by a standard application of Van Kampen's Theorem, and the set $J$ is defined in the second sentence of the second paragraph of the proof. Perhaps it will be clearer if one assigns some notation.
Consider any connected graph $G$ (in this application, $G=\overline X$). Let $T \subset G$ be any maximal spanning tree $T$. Fix a choice of base point $u \in G$. For every other vertex $v$ let $\gamma(v)$ denote the unique path in $T$ from $u$ to $v$. Let $\{e_i\}_I$ be an indexing of the edges of $G \setminus T$. For each $i$, let $e_i$ be assigned an orientation with initial vertex $v_i$ and terminal vertex $w_i$. Starting with the fact that the tree $T$ is contractible, by application of Van Kampen's Theorem one proves that the set of loops
$$\{\gamma(v_i) \, e_i \, \bar\gamma(w_i)\}_{i \in I}
$$
represents a free generating set of $\pi_1(G,u)$. That set is precisely the "set of loops [based at $u$] with exactly one edge not in $T$".
The set $J$ is defined in the second sentence of the first paragraph, using $G=\overline X$: letting $f : \overline X \to X$ be the covering map, $J$ is represented by the set of closed paths $f(\gamma(v))$, one for each vertex $v \in \overline X$. A key feature here is that for any path $\gamma(v)$ in $J$, if $v'$ is the 2nd to last vertex in $\gamma(v)$ then $\gamma(v')$ is the initial subpath of $\gamma(v)$ obtained by omitting the final edge of $\gamma(v)$. Iterating this construction shows that every initial segment of an element of $J$ is also an element of $J$.

Thanks! Bit late but I'm also confused about where $ts(\overline{ts})^{-1}$ comes from
